# SciPy + Numpy: Finding the slope of a sigmoid curve

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, least-squares

I have some data that follow a sigmoid distribution as you can see in the following image: [image: Sigmoid data for 2003]

After normalizing and scaling my data, I have adjusted the curve at the bottom using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` and some initial parameters:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid_function, xdata, ydata, p0 = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05])
>>> print popt
[  2.82019932e+02  -1.90996563e-01   5.00000000e-02]
```

So `popt`, according to [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), returns *"Optimal values for the parameters so that the sum of the squared error of f(xdata, *popt) - ydata is minimized"*. I understand here that there is no calculation of the slope with `curve_fit`, because I do **not** think the slope of this gentle curve is 282, neither is negative.

Then I tried with `scipy.optimize.leastsq`, because the documentation says it returns *"The solution (or the result of the last iteration for an unsuccessful call).*", so I thought the slope would be returned. Like this:

```
p, cov, infodict, mesg, ier = leastsq(residuals, p_guess, args = (nxdata, nydata), full_output=True)
>>> print p
Param(x0=281.73193626250207, y0=-0.012731420027056234, c=1.0069006606656596, k=0.18836680131910222)
```

But again, I did not get what I expected. `curve_fit` and `leastsq` returned almost the same values, with is not surprising I guess, as `curve_fit` is using an implementation of the least squares method within to find the curve. But no slope back...unless I overlooked something.

So, **how to calculate the slope in a point, say, where X = 285 and Y = 0.5?**

I am trying to avoid manual methods, like [calculating the derivative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DV8MJCBzkM) in, say, (285.5, 0.55) and (284.5, 0.45) and subtract and divide results and so. I would like to know if there is a more automatic method for this.

Thank you all!

**EDIT #1**

This is my "sigmoid_function", used by curve_fit and leastsq methods:

```
def sigmoid_function(xdata, x0, k, p0): # p0 not used anymore, only its components (x0, k)
    # This function is called by two different methods: curve_fit and leastsq,
    # this last one through function "residuals". I don't know if it makes sense
    # to use a single function for two (somewhat similar) methods, but there 
    # it goes.

    # p0:
    #   + Is the initial parameter for scipy.optimize.curve_fit. 
    #   + For residuals calculation is left empty
    #   + It is initialized to [0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
    # x0:
    #   + Is the convergence parameter in X-axis and also the shift
    #   + It starts with 0.05 and ends up being around ~282 (days in a year)
    # k:
    #   + Set up either by curve_fit or leastsq
    #   + In least squares it is initially fixed at 0.5 and in curve_fit
    #   + to 0.05. Why? Just did this approach in two different ways and 
    #   + it seems it is working. 
    #   + But honestly, I have no clue on what it represents
    # xdata: 
    #   + Positions in X-axis. In this case from 240 to 365

# Finally I changed those parameters as suggested in the answer. 
# Sigmoid curve has 2 degrees of freedom, therefore, the initial 
# guess only needs to be this size. In this case, p0 = [282, 0.5]


    y = np.exp(-k*(xdata-x0)) / (1 + np.exp(-k*(xdata-x0)))
    return y

def residuals(p_guess, xdata, ydata):
    # For the residuals calculation, there is no need of setting up the initial parameters
    # After fixing the initial guess and sigmoid_function header, remove [] 
    # return ydata - sigmoid_function(xdata, p_guess[0], p_guess[1], [])
    return ydata - sigmoid_function(xdata, p_guess[0], p_guess[1], [])
```

I am sorry if I made mistakes while describing the parameters or confused technical terms. I am very new with numpy and I have not studied maths for years, so I am catching up again.

So, again, what is your advice to **calculate the slope of X = 285, Y = 0.5 (more or less the midpoint)** for this dataset? Thanks!!

**EDIT #2**

Thanks to Oliver W., I updated my code as he suggested and understood a bit better the problem.

There is a final detail I do not fully get. Apparently, `curve_fit` returns a `popt` array (x0, k) with the optimum parameters for the fitting:

- `x0` seems to be how shifted is the curve by indicating the central point of the curve
- `k` parameter is the slope when y = 0.5, also in the center of the curve (I think!)

Why if the sigmoid function is a growing one, the derivative/slope in popt is negative? Does it make sense?

I used `sigmoid_derivative` to calculate the slope and, yes, I obtained the same results that `popt` but with positive sign.

```
# Year 2003, 2005, 2007. Slope in midpoint.
k = [-0.1910, -0.2545, -0.2259] # Values coming from popt
slope = [0.1910, 0.2545, 0.2259] # Values coming from sigmoid_derivative function
```

I know this is being a bit peaky because I could use both. The relevant data is in there but with negative sign, but I was wondering why is this happening.

So, the calculation of the derivative function as you suggested, is only required if I **need to know the slope in other points than y = 0.5**. Only for midpoint, I can use `popt`.

Thanks for your help, it saved me a lot of time. :-)

Comment: can you also add the `sigmoid_function` you are using and explain what are the parameters you are expecting?

Comment: according to [THIS POST](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72388/estimating-the-slope-of-the-straight-portion-of-a-sigmoid-curve) in stats.stackexchange.com, I can see that you can only get the slope of a sigmoid curve where the curve straightens. So you need to give the `x_lower` and `x_upper` limits of the part of the curve for which you need the slope in your `sigmoid_function`

Comment: Is the slope one of the fit parameters? 282 is obviously the shift of the curve on the x-axis (compared to a regular sigmoidal). At which point would you like to get the slope? The slope varies along the curve. Like ThePredator already wrote, it would be helfpful to see your `sigmoid_function` to be able to see what your fit parameters mean.

Comment: Added code as you suggested, hope I can provide useful information. Thanks. The idea is calculating the slope in the midpoint, where Y = 0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never using the parameter `p0` you're passing to your sigmoid function. Hence, curve fitting will not have any good measure to find convergence, because it can take any value for this parameter. You should first rewrite your sigmoid function like this:

```
def sigmoid_function(xdata, x0, k):

    y = np.exp(-k*(xdata-x0)) / (1 + np.exp(-k*(xdata-x0)))
    return y
```

This means your model (the sigmoid) has only two degrees of freedom. This will be returned in `popt`:

```
initial_guess = [282, 1]  # (x0, k): at x0, the sigmoid reaches 50%, k is slope related
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid_function, xdata, ydata, p0=initial_guess)
```

Now `popt` will be a tuple (or array of 2 values), being the best possible `x0` and `k`.

To get the slope of this function at any point, to be honest, I would just calculate the derivative symbolically as the sigmoid is not such a hard function. You will end up with:

```
def sigmoid_derivative(x, x0, k):
    f = np.exp(-k*(x-x0))
    return -k / f
```

If you have the results from your curve fitting stored in `popt`, you could pass this easily to this function:

```
print(sigmoid_derivative(285, *popt))
```

which will return for you the derivative at `x=285`. But, because you ask specifically for the midpoint, so when `x==x0` and `y==.5`, you'll see (from the sigmoid_derivative) that the derivative there is just `-k`, which can be observed immediately from the `curve_fit` output you've already obtained. In the output you've shown, that's about 0.19.

Comment: Initial guess has been fixed, because you were right: despite curve_fit was converging, values were not correct. I used them previously in a normalized (y-values between 0 and 1) fitting and I just recycled it. I also rewrote sigmoid_function and sigmoid_derivative as you suggested and calculated the slope in x = 282, point where about 50% observations are accumulated.

However, there is something that I still do not understand and is bothering me, so I will edit my post to add more information. Thank you very much for your help, I would appreciate if you can review this re-edition.

Comment: Technically you have to post a new question for that (because your original one you've marked as answered), but because the answer is short, I'll add it here: the way you've defined the sigmoid (mathematically) will ensure that the parameter `k` is the *negative* of the slope at the point where `x==x0`. It follows straight from the  definition and its symbolically calculated derivative. `curve_fit` does not "interpret" the parameters it is trying to optimize. So it doesn't know that `k` is related to the slope (`* -1`), it just gives you the best fitting k-value for the function you pass.

Comment: All clear, it's me who was interpreting beyond numpy's functionality. Thanks!!